# Creating a Table without a caption

Tags: lyx

I'm using LyX and would like to suppress any caption under a Table. How can I do that?

Comment: I tagged this as lyx as it can only be a lyx question: in latex you only get a caption if you use `\caption` if you don't use `\caption ` you get no caption.

Comment: Thanks. The problem arises for me because, if I insert the table as a float, the caption "Table 1" appears and I want to get rid of that. If I insert the Table directly (not as a float), I don't get a caption (great!) but then I can't seem to center the table. So an alternative question would be: how can I center a Table that is not a float?

Comment: \centering \begin{tabular}{ccc}... makes a centered table you don't want a float (putting it on a floating environment doesn't centre it or change its horizontal position in any way) I can't help with lyx as I've never seen it, but lyx is supposed to make things easier not harder and all you need to do here is _not_ use \caption.

Comment: @PankajTandon Can you just delete the caption? Right after you do Insert > Float > Table, press delete.

Comment: @scottkosty That worked! Since the cursor is located in the space to insert a caption and I had never entered anything there, it never occurred to me that hitting delete would remove the LyX-generated caption. Thanks very much!

Comment: @PankajTandon Glad it works!

Answer (score 2):

Right after you do Insert > Float > Table, press backspace.